# Flightradar24.com track info

Tags: online-tracking

What is the meaning of the **track** info found on Flightradar24, as seen below?

Would be the angle between the route and the equator?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate - FR24 doesn't quite follow normal aviation 'practice'.

Answer (score 5):

That is the angle between true north and the current ground track. FR24 is slightly different to (most) aviation in that it uses true north instead of magnetic north as the datum.

Answer (score 1):

Track is the heading the aircraft is actually tracking over the earth's surface. This is different from the heading that the aircraft is flying, as wind does change the directional component over the earths surface.